# Downstream job not getting triggered from conditional step

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job while executing will procure liquibase db lock. If something goes wrong, the job exits without releasing the lock. So i need to trigger next job on failure so that it unlocks the db and other jobs using the DB will not throw up error due to this lock.

```
......
[ERROR]: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by srvcldpcld262 since 4/28/17 8:40 AM
[ERROR]: SEVERE 4/28/17 10:48 AM: liquibase: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by srvcldpcld262 since 4/28/17 8:40 AM
[ERROR]: liquibase.exception.LockException: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by srvcldpcld262 since 4/28/17 8:40 AM
[ERROR]:    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:173)
[ERROR]:    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:182)
[ERROR]:    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:174)
[ERROR]:    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:997)
...........
```

The error will be something like the above. Now I have configured a conditional step which will run the Regular expression match like the below:

```
Expression: ^.*\s.*Could not acquire change log lock.*\s\[.*\s*
Label: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX,regex="Could\snot\sacquire\schange\slog\slock"}
```

On the execution the log is as follows:

```
Regular expression run condition: Expression=[Could\snot\sacquire\schange\slog\slock], Label=[[...truncated 1841 lines...]
[ERROR]: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by srvcldpcld262 since 4/28/17 11:58 AM
[ERROR]: SEVERE 4/28/17 12:13 PM: liquibase: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by srvcldpcld262 since 4/28/17 11:58 AM
[ERROR]: liquibase.exception.LockException: Could not acquire change log lock.  Currently locked by srvcldpcld262 since 4/28/17 11:58 AM
[...truncated 212 lines...]
]
Run condition [Regular expression match] preventing perform for step [Trigger/call builds on other projects]
```

Could you please help with the label and expression part on how it needs to configured? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the expression and the label was not matching.
Exp: .*MATCH.*
Label: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="Could not acquire change log lock", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=0, maxMatches=1, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=true, substText="MATCH", addNewline=false}
We had to look for "Could not acquire change log lock" in the build logs and then perform the action. Please note the expression within label is deduced using java expression lang. The subsText and the Exp should match meaning the whole of the line containing the text "Could not acquire change log lock" will be greped by "MATCH" keyword. addNewline is added as after grepping in the logs, new line was getting added.